# Example of closure in "Javascript: The good parts"

Tags: javascript

I am reading about closures in "Javascript: The Good Parts" book.

There is following example of using closures:

```
var add_the_handlers = function (nodes) {
var i;
   for (i = 0; i < nodes.length; i += 1) {
      nodes[i].onclick = function (i) {
         return function (e) {
            alert(i + ":" + e);
         };
      }(i);
   }
};
```

Is it correct example? Or much correct example would be following?

```
var add_the_handlers = function (nodes) {
var i;
   for (i = 0; i < nodes.length; i += 1) {
      nodes[i].onclick = function (idx) {
         return function (e) {
            alert(idx + ":" + e);
         };
      }(i);
   }
};
```

Variable i in the outer function and variable i in the inner function "nodes[i].onclick = function (i)" - it is two different variables. 
And third function accesses variable from second function, not from the outermost.
Am I correct?

Comment: Both versions do the same thing. In my opinion your version is easier to read since the variable names are different. In a general sense, when you have variables of the same name in different scopes, the one that will be used is the one defined closest to (or in) the current scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two examples are identical.  The whole point of a closure is to make an outer-scoped variable (i) into an inner-scoped variable (i/idx/foo, take your pick).  The closure creates a "copy" of the variable, so that when the callback gets made, it has the correct value.

```
// outer-scoped i changes on each iteration
var i;

for (i = 0; i < nodes.length; i += 1) {
   nodes[i].onclick = function (i) {

      // here i now refers to a different variable; while the outer i keeps iterating,  
      //this i is preserved at its current value.
      return function (e) {
         alert(i + ":" + e);
      };
   }(i);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that closure creates a "copy" of the variable? From the book - "It is important to understand that the inner function has access to the actual variables
of the outer functions and not copies in order to avoid the following problem".

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the example correct. The `i` variable that you see as function parameter takes precedence over the outer `i` variable because it is declared in the local scope.

Answer (score 0):

From javascript point of view - these two are identical. Therefore it's the question of taste. If you would have more closures inside, then it would be a good idea to use different names. But here the example is so simple - there is no need for that.

Comment: From javascript point of view - these two examples are identical. But it is rather difficult to understand that there are two different variables i in following function call - "function (i) {} (i)".

Answer (score 0):

No, the two examples you posted is exactly the same. The only difference is just the parameter name for an function, but that doesn't matter, you could use whatever.